# Composer not using key set through SSH agent forwarding

Tags: ssh, vagrant, composer-php, ssh-agent

I'm using SSH agent forwarding with my Vagrant box. It looks like this is set up correctly, as I can successfully perform a git clone on my private repository:

`$ git clone git@github.com:myorganisation/myrepo.git`

`Cloning into 'myrepo'...`

This repository also features in my composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url":  "git@github.com:myorganisation/myrepo.git"
},
```

However when I run `composer update` under the same user, I get an error indicating that I'm unauthenticated:

`The "https://api.github.com/repos/com:myorganisation/myrepo" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)`

How can I instruct Composer to use my forwarded key?

Answer (score 1):

I sorted this by adding the `no-api` option:

```
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "no-api": true,
    "url":  "git@github.com:myorganisation/myrepo.git"
}
```